# Bash: Find most recent N files with filename beginning with some string

Tags: bash

I know how to find N latest files,

```
ls -latr | tail -n32
```

And I know how to find N files of filename beginning with some string,

```
ls filestring* | tail -n32
```

But I want to find the fifty latest files whose filenames begin with some string.

Comment: For human review or scripted use? `ls -t` is the right thing for your own use; it's not the right thing for a script.

Comment: Plug for `zsh`, which is better suited for this type of task: `print -l filestring*(om[1,50])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -lt fileprefix* | head -32
```

there is no need to reverse sort and tail.

Comment: This won't work if there are more files starting with that prefix than will fit on a single command line.

Answer (score 1):

The following requires GNU `find` and `sort`, but works with all possible filenames (including names with newlines), and on directories where the number of files starting with the given prefix doesn't fit into `ARG_MAX`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
files=( )
counter=32
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' timestamp &&
      IFS= read -r -d '' filename &&
      (( --counter >= 0 )); do
  files+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zgr)

declare -p files ## print the generated array of filenames
```

- Using `-printf '%T@ %p\0'` prints each result with the UNIX timestamp (seconds-since-epoch); a space; the filename; and then a NUL.
- `sort -z` tells `sort` to use NULs (which, unlike newlines, can't exist in filenames) to delimit input and output records.
- `IFS= read -r -d ' ' timestamp && IFS= read -r -d '' filename` reads content up to the space in a given record into the variable `timestamp`, and reads everything up to the next NUL into the variable `filename`.

See [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for a discussion of sorting or comparing files based on metadata, and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).